# C# Repository and Unit of Work Patterns

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository

Can someone point me to a good, real world example of using these patterns together in c#? That is to say, not just a CRUD example, but something where for instance, you would do things like say, create a series of child records at the same time that you then update the parent record in one unit?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265/unit-of-work-pattern-in-net, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995227/can-anyone-recommend-good-tutorial-on-repository-and-unit-of-work-pattern-usage